# Find the previous non-blank value from a column using a value in an adjacent column as search key

Tags: google-sheets

How can i VLOOKUP from a text to the left and if its nothing on the left to keep going up until find a text.

Basically the i want to vlookup the invoice from the model. so if there is no text on the left cell of the model to keep going up until it finds a cell with text and extract that info.

examples in the picture.
[image]

so if i want to look for the invoice of the model G10-B the function needs to go one cell left and if there is no text to go up until find some text, in this example goes up until find the cell 2021-C-MI

this is my sample spreadsheets https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iefvYAg96rV16c6ARFrd5V5WZKU_j70JZzQn1tD0568/edit?usp=sharing here is the source sheet and here is the search sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TvQHDeW8yMJVCeXrzWGYGDMY0wGEDBd_fIzISMZZ-Rw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Why the google-apps-script tag? Besides clarifying this in the question body, show what you tried and a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: It will help to know the actual ranges of the two columns of data. And if you are going to do the search in a different sheet (recommended), what is the name of the source sheet (the one with the original data)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added two sheets to your `SEARCH SHEET` spreadsheet.

The first is called `IMPORT`. This sheet brings over *all* data from Columns A and B of the `INVOICE-MODEL` sheet. It is currently Hidden, since it will not be needed for direct reference.

I then duplicated your `SEARCH` sheet and renamed it `Erik Help`, just to keep things separated, in case someone else wants to jump in and help.

The formula in `'Erik Help'!B2` references the new `IMPORT` sheet to find the correct invoice:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B1;{IMPORT!B3:B\ROW(IMPORT!B3:B)};2;FALSE);0);FILTER({ROW(IMPORT!A3:A)\IMPORT!A3:A};IMPORT!A3:A<>"");2;TRUE);"NOT FOUND"))`

Two `VLOOKUP`s are performed. The innermost `VLOOKUP` finds the row number of the model number on the `IMPORT` sheet. Then the outermost `VLOOKUP` uses this row number to search a `FILTER`ed set from `IMPORT!B3:B` where Column A is not null/blank. Since rows are always in sequential order, I could use `TRUE` as the final parameter of this outermost `VLOOKUP`, which will bump backward to find the last match that is lower than the search.

So, if your model is found in Row 5, the outermost `VLOOKUP` will search for 5 (which is blank in `IMPORT!A:A`) and just bounce back to Row 3 (which is not blank in `IMPORT!A:A`). Once this closest occupied Row number is found, the corresponding invoice from `IMPORT!A:A` is returned.

You will notice that I also applied Data Validation to cell B1, which is drawing from `IMPORT!B3:B`. This will assure that you don't accidentally enter a model which does not exist.

Comment: Yes ! thank you very much Erik! :)

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that invoices and models are in `A2:B`, you can look up the first matching invoice for the model in cell `E2` like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    vlookup( 
      E2, 
      { 
        B2:B, 
        iferror( 
          vlookup( 
            row(A2:A), 
            if( len(A2:A), { row(A2:A), A2:A } ), 
            2, 
            true 
          ) 
        ) 
      }, 
      2, 
      false  
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

To look up the first matching invoice for a whole column of models in `E2:E`, replace `E2` with `E2:E` in the formula.

To use the formula in a spreadsheet whose locale uses semicolons instead of commas as argument separators, modify the formula like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    vlookup( 
      E2; 
      { 
        B2:B \ 
        iferror( 
          vlookup( 
            row(A2:A); 
            if( len(A2:A); { row(A2:A) \ A2:A } ); 
            2; 
            true 
          ) 
        ) 
      }; 
      2; 
      false  
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: Hello thank you!! i tried to use the function but appears error this is my sample spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iefvYAg96rV16c6ARFrd5V5WZKU_j70JZzQn1tD0568/edit?usp=sharing here is the source sheet and here is the search sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TvQHDeW8yMJVCeXrzWGYGDMY0wGEDBd_fIzISMZZ-Rw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hey! i tried again and it worked!!!!! thankssss!

Comment: Edited the answer to show how to use the formula in the Spanish locale.