# How to vlookup multiple values and that values to be in a drop-down list?

Tags: google-sheets

I asked before how can. `"Find the previous non-blank value from a column using a value in an adjacent column as search key (https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/155482/find-the-previous-non-blank-value-from-a-column-using-a-value-in-an-adjacent-col)"` this is my sample spreadsheets https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iefvYAg96rV16c6ARFrd5V5WZKU_j70JZzQn1tD0568/edit?usp=sharing
here is the source sheet and here is the search sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TvQHDeW8yMJVCeXrzWGYGDMY0wGEDBd_fIzISMZZ-Rw/edit?usp=sharing

It works fine but when the model repeats it just appeared the first choice or " no found"

how can i search one model and if it repeats to find all the matches(invoices)  and all the matches to be in a drop-down list? if its too hard maybe can give me a clue so i can investigate it how to do it! :D
thanks!! xoxo

Comment: Hi again. Question and request - Q: why don't you fill in the model numbers and avoid the pain? Request: would you please edit your question and "SEARCH" spreadsheet to show how a successful outcome would appear in the event of a model being on multiple invoices.

Comment: ok, I cant fill in the model numbers :( because im not the owner of the spreadsheet but thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    left(1 / len(B2:B); 0) 
    & 
    vlookup( 
      row('Hoja 1'!A2:A); 
      if( len('Hoja 1'!A2:A); { row('Hoja 1'!A2:A) \ 'Hoja 1'!A2:A } ); 
      2; 
      true 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

```
={ 'Hoja 1'!B2:B }
```

```
=iferror( filter(IMPORT!A2:A; len(IMPORT!B2:B); IMPORT!B2:B = B1) )
```

See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TvQHDeW8yMJVCeXrzWGYGDMY0wGEDBd_fIzISMZZ-Rw/edit#gid=1873866917).

Comment: thank you! got it :)